# Elastic vs DB for regular search?

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, lucene, bigdata

I have joined a new company where I observed the below use case.

Use case :- A table has around 500 GB of data. Data is user action events for each and every user activity. Purpose is to analyse the activity count
for different permutation and combination for any given date range. So data is further supplied to elastic(and lucene in different similar scenario use case).

My understanding is for this kind of scenario DB in itself should be sufficient.But When I try to query the DB for specific permutation and combination for given data range its damn slow and most of the time gets times out.

But when I to fetch same combination with elastic(or lucene), it is much faster. There is no full text search support required here.

Not sure what is causing the elastic(or lucene) to be much faster than SQL based DB even for regular(not full text) search ?

what can be the probable reason for the same ? I can think of two reasons here

1. Elastic(or lucene) keeps the data in compressed form. So may be it is quicker to search here ?
2. Elastic may help to achieve the parallelism with data kept in multiple shards by default. But in lucene  case tI do not even see any parallelism.

Comment: Different technologies are optimized for different purposes.  In addition, each technology has optimization methods that you may or may not be using.  Your question is too broad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Per my understanding lucene or elastic  are suited for full text search anf for regular column based search , rdbms should be fine. What I am asking is just what can be possible reasoning where lucene or elastic can server faster even for scenarios without full text search ?

Comment: @emily . . . Most databases, including MySQL, support full text search.

Comment: @emilly For regular column based search, in a RDBMS you must index the column so that it is fast. As the number of rows increases the performance degrades if the column is not index. Indexing each and every column in RDBMS would heavily impact on adding/updating records and also in storage. In elasticsearch, by default every field (column) is indexed. Elastic is built and optimised for search,  be it full text search or simple column based. This is where it will outperform RDBMS.

Comment: @NishantSaini  That's what I want to know what makes elastic better for simple column based search than RDBMS ? Also I believe even in elastic , adding/updating the value will be of same impact as in RDBMS as it has to do resort again. Is n't it ?

Comment: This is a very broad question to answer. Both have their own advantages and disadvantages.